# POSIXct formatting in R?

Tags: r, posixct

I'm trying to convert characters into a POSIXct format using lubridate's parse date_time function.

This is my code:

```
df$TimeClosed <- parse_date_time(df$TimeClosed, 'mdy HMSp')
```

Most of my variables are in this format : 09/12/2017 11:08:51 AM

but there are some that are like this : 7/6/19 15:37

and because of that, they are failing to parse.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this so all date/times are in POSIX and in the same format?

Thanks,

Comment: The problem is the lack of seconds. A standard trick is to `paste0(., ":00")` first then coerce to POSIXct. Or `lubridate::mdy_hm("7/6/19 15:37")`, also a standard way.

Answer (score 0):

`parse_date_time` can take a vector of formats and will try them one by one in order until one matches.

```
library (lubridate)

x <- c("09/12/2017 11:08:51 AM", "7/6/19 15:37")
parse_date_time(x, c("dmYHMSp", "dmyHM"))
## [1] "2017-12-09 11:08:51 UTC" "2019-06-07 15:37:00 UTC"
```